# Sum and merge rows in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sum dublicate rows in the amount column like shown in the screenshot:

[image: how I would like to sum]

So if report_name, line_item and column_item are the same I want to sum the amounts in the amount row and create one row instead of two but without losing the structure of the dataframe.
But I don't want to sum dublicates if they have column_item 50 or 30.

This is my data frame:

```
entity;business_line_group;conso_level_entity;report_name;line_item;column_item;z_axis;value_text;amount;approval_text
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0050;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;40409261.0100539;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0040;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;46860662.1948734;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0060;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;1783648.53838003;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0070;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;7847645.76582712;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0310;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;48100909.2077918;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0201;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;45652287.0078367;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0590;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;19988230.281333;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0480;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;28243908.6235795;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0490;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;12655653.8647408;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0530;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;27792100.4510517;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0570;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;20768476.5051213;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0480;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;28601515.4535418;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0490;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;17269663.9202129;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0530;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;21250486.2477187;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0570;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;12924566.8399212;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0110;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;17299383.641137;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0035;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;19054145.8837998;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0280;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;294348.91379545;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0340;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;40803729.9712868;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0240;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;25387904.3875074;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0340;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;6951075.43742419;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0240;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;12298844.1430509;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0040;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0050;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0060;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0070;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0090;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0110;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0240;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0260;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0080;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0100;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0120;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0130;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0140;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.95;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0150;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0170;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0190;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.93;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0200;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.88;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0250;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0270;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0280;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0290;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0320;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0330;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0340;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0350;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0360;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0370;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0380;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0390;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0400;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0410;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0420;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0430;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.6;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0440;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.45;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0450;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0460;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0040;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0070;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0090;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.03;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0110;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0260;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0310;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0480;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0490;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0530;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0570;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0590;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0080;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0140;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0150;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0170;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0190;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0200;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0250;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0280;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0290;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0360;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0370;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0380;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0390;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0400;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0420;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0430;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0450;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0035;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0180;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0204;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0206;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0207;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0220;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0230;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0300;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0510;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0520;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0540;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0560;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0600;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0610;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0630;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0640;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0660;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0670;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0680;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0700;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0710;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0890;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0900;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0913;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0914;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0915;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0916;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0917;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0918;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0940;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0950;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0960;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0970;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0980;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0990;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1000;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1010;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1030;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1050;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1060;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1070;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1080;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1090;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0040;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0060;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0070;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0090;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0201;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0260;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0080;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0130;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0150;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0170;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0190;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0180;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0230;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0160;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0210;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0269;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0273;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0277;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0281;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0285;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0289;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0293;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0301;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0303;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0309;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0313;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0317;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0321;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0325;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0329;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0333;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0341;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0343;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0345;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0070;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;5198630.14;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0190;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;835892217.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0260;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;4745984333.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0035;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;25424822307.28;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0070;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-33216232069.67;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0080;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-20966122130.53;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0110;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-9384698955.8;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0230;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;2193605666.84;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0250;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-573769151.28;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0260;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;3333715453.55;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0918;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;124366.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0160;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-54345799619.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0260;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;150348.16;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-37633449687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;0020;UNDEFINED;n/a;-3764349687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;0040;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;0040;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;335098209.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;7449687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;76449687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0050;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;40409261.0100539;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0040;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;46860662.1948734;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0060;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;1783648.53838003;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0070;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;7847645.76582712;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0310;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;48100909.2077918;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0201;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;45652287.0078367;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0590;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;19988230.281333;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0480;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;28243908.6235795;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0490;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;12655653.8647408;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0530;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;27792100.4510517;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0570;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;20768476.5051213;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0480;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;28601515.4535418;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0490;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;17269663.9202129;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0530;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;21250486.2477187;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0570;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;12924566.8399212;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0110;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;17299383.641137;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0035;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;19054145.8837998;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0280;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;294348.91379545;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0340;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;40803729.9712868;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0240;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;25387904.3875074;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0340;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;6951075.43742419;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0240;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;12298844.1430509;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0040;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0050;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0060;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0070;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0090;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0110;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0240;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0260;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0080;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0100;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0120;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0130;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0140;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.95;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0150;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0170;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0190;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.93;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0200;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.88;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0250;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0270;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0280;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0290;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0320;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0330;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0340;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0350;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0360;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0370;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0380;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0390;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0400;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0410;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0420;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0430;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.6;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0440;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.45;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0450;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0460;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0040;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0070;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0090;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.03;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0110;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0260;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0310;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0480;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0490;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0530;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0570;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0590;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0080;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0140;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0150;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0170;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0190;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0200;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0250;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0280;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0290;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0360;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0370;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0380;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0390;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0400;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0420;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0430;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0450;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0035;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0180;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0204;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0206;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0207;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0220;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0230;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0300;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0510;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0520;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0540;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0560;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0600;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0610;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0630;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0640;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0660;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0670;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0680;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0700;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0710;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0890;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0900;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0913;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0914;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0915;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0916;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0917;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0918;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0940;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0950;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0960;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0970;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0980;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0990;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1000;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1010;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1030;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1050;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1060;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1070;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1080;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1090;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;0050;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0040;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0060;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0070;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0090;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0201;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0260;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0080;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0130;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0150;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0170;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0190;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0180;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0230;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0160;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0210;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0269;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0273;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0277;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0281;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0285;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0289;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0293;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0301;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0303;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0309;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0313;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0317;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0321;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0325;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0329;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0333;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0341;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0343;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0345;0080;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0070;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;5198630.14;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0190;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;835892217.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;0260;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;4745984333.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0035;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;25424822307.28;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0070;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-33216232069.67;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0080;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-20966122130.53;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0110;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-9384698955.8;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0230;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;2193605666.84;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0250;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-573769151.28;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0260;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;3333715453.55;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;0918;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;124366.0;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0160;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-54345799619.07;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;0260;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;150348.16;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;-37633449687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;0020;UNDEFINED;n/a;-3764349687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;0040;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;0040;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;0030;UNDEFINED;n/a;335098209.05;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;7449687.15;22/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;0010;UNDEFINED;n/a;76449687.15;22/03/2022
```

I hope you can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because need omit sum values by condition first filter for not match condition, get sum with remove duplicates and then add rows by condition:

```
m = df['column_item'].isin([30, 50])
df1 = df[~m].copy()
df1['amount'] = df1.groupby(['report_name', 'line_item', 'column_item'])['amount'].transform('sum')
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['report_name', 'line_item', 'column_item'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df[m]])
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it summed the values in 30 and 50

Comment: @Christoffer - so condition `m = df['column_item'].isin([30, 50])` not working?

Comment: @Christoffer - `30` and `50` are strings, so need `m = df['column_item'].isin(['30', '50'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get just duplicated rows and sum over them, you can do something like:

```py
(df[(df[["report_name", "line_item","column_item"]].duplicated(keep=False)) & (~df['column_item'].isin([30, 50]))]
    .groupby(["report_name", "line_item","column_item"])["amount"]
    .sum())
```

This will result in something like:

```py
report_name  line_item  column_item
C_72_00_a    50         10             4.040926e+07
             70         10             5.198630e+06
             190        10             8.358922e+08
             260        10             4.745984e+09
             280        10             2.943489e+05
                                           ...     
C_74_00_a    329        80             3.500000e-01
             333        80             5.000000e-01
             341        80             5.000000e-01
             343        80             1.000000e+00
             345        80             1.000000e+00
Name: amount, Length: 67, dtype: float64
```

To make sure that you are getting the correct values let's check the example you have shown in your question ( the one with `C_73_00_a` and `1100` and `10`):

```py
dfResult = (df[(df[["report_name", "line_item","column_item"]].duplicated(keep=False)) & (~df['column_item'].isin([30, 50]))]
    .groupby(["report_name", "line_item","column_item"])["amount"]
    .sum())
dfResult[('C_73_00_a',   1100, 10)]
```

This will output:

```
-75266899374.3
```

Which is the result of `-37633449687.15 + -37633449687.15` (as shown in your question).